# prepareForSegue called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath only when third segue is added

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I have 3 segues to 3 different views.  2 are implemented with no problem, it is when the third is created that the problems occur.

I have the following didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@" ----------  did select row");

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(indexPath.row == [self.data count]-1){
            //prior to adding this, everything works
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MoreComments" sender:self];
        }else{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FriendView" sender:friend];
        }
    }else if(indexPath.section == 1){
        if(indexPath.row == [self.data2 count]-1){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MorePosts" sender:self];
        }else{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FriendView" sender:friend];
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following prepareForSeque method:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MorePosts"]){
        MorePostsViewController *mfamvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        mfamvc.data = self.data;
    }else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FriendView"]){
        FriendViewController *fvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        fvc.friend = friend;
    }else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MoreComments"]){
          MoreCommentsViewController *mcvc = segue.destinationViewController;
          mcvc.data = self.data2;
    }
}
```

Before control dragging from my cell to the last view I can see that my program hits didselectrow and then prepareforseque.  This makes all the view navigation work perfect.

As soon as I control drag from my cell to the MoreCommentsViewController I start to see the error:

nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

I notice that now also prepareforseque is being called twice, with prepareforseque being called first, then didselectrow, then prepareforsegue again.

What am I doing wrong to conditionally go to these different views?

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the ways the segues are connected up. Can you describe what you did in IB or post a link to an image of your storyboard? Are you connecting multiple segues directly from one cell prototype? If so, that's what's wrong.

Comment: yes i am connecting multiple segues from one cell prototype.  I guess that is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is you can't drag from a tableview cell to multiple views.  As @rdelmar mentioned this is wrong.  You should drag from the destination to the source view and then handle manually the way I did above.

Also can be found here:  [Conditional segue performed on tap on UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942942/conditional-segue-performed-on-tap-on-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 83):

You should use either `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or segues from cell, but not both. If you want your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to invoke segues, those segues should *not* be from the cell to the next scene, but rather from the view controller icon in the bar above the scene:

[image: segue between view controllers]

You can now select this new segue, go to the "attributes inspector" (<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>), and supply a storyboard identifier which you can reference in your code when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: How do you get the destinationViewController with this method?

Comment: @rigdonmr - whether you have added a segue in interface builder, or you have programmatically called `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, either way, `prepareForSegue` will be called, and you can then reference `segue.destinationViewController` there.

Comment: Thanks for help  :-)