# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which when you select a row, it will lead you into the "details" of the selected row. However, the first time I click the row, it goes into the `prepareForSegue` method, without calling  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. When I push the back button on the detail view, the app goes back, and if I select the row again, the method will be called.

I'm **NOT** using the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

This patter will continue and I can't figure out why. When I load my data, I do call `[tableview reloadData]`.

I have also tried to add `self.TagsTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;` to my `viewDidLoad` method.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.bluetoothManager = [[BlueToothLEManager alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTableView:) name:@"ScanComplete" object:nil];


    self.Tags = self.bluetoothManager.Tags; 
    NSLog(@"Fetch Tags: %@", self.Tags); 
}
...
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* cell = [fetchTagsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tagCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"tagCell"];
    }

    FetchTag* newTag = [fetchTags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", newTag.tagName, indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [newTag.tagUUID UUIDString];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedTagFromTable =  [fetchTags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [TagsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailView"]){
        TagDetailViewController* ftdvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [ftdvc setSelectedTag:selectedTagFromTable];


    }
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

-(void)reloadTableView:(NSNotification*)notif{
    NSLog(@"Reloading Table View");
    NSLog(@"Fetch Tags: %@", self.Tags); 
    [self.TagsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: So you are expecting to use a storyboard segue to navigate automatically on selection _and_ call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? I'm not sure I would trust that. I suggest deleting the automatic segue, and instead calling the segue manually (or just doing the navigation manually) _in_ `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: And are you even using custom cells? Are you pre-populating the "fetchTagsTableView" cells (i.e. UITableViewCell* cell = [fetchTagsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tagCell"];) somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18165684/335858

Comment: @matt I'm using `didSelectRowAtIndex` to populate an object with data, the using `prepareSegue` to send the data to the new view controller. Is this not the right way to do this? Sorry, I'm new to iOS. I come from a Java/Android background. I'm still trying to figure this stuff out.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I already told you what I think is the "right way"; I don't see what you're asking me except to repeat myself.

Comment: @matt I'm asking you HOW you would do that.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Well, that would be a new question! What is it that you don't know? How to run a segue in code? How to push a view controller in code? Do you know what a view controller _is_? Are you in a navigation controller interface? Do you know what a navigation controller is? How far back do you need me to go? This section of my book describes (and gives code for) what I usually do when the user taps on a row of my table: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_table_view_selection

Comment: @matt, thanks but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would have put the code from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to the prepareForSegue: instead  Try using the sender parameter to identify a selected tag