# How to use pushviewcontroller on uitableviewcell swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I create a new `UITableviewcell.swift` from `UITableView`, and I want to use alert button to push `UITableView` to other view.

I try to use some method of `instantiateViewController` as below:

```
let sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
```

and I try:

1. `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` (uitableviewcell has no member navigationController)
2. as above, use `self.window?.rootViewController?` to replace `Self` ,but it's useless (my `RootView` is `SWRevealViewController`)

How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773529/open-new-view-controller-by-clicking-cell-in-table-view-swift-ios. The next time first do some reseach before asking the question.

Comment: thank you for your reply much appreciated, I searching for it over 3 days

Comment: sorry for my stupidity

Answer (score 0):

This may be help for you

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath path: NSIndexPath!) {
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, the question has been solved (for me :D)

```
let sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let frontVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC1")
let frontNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: frontVC)
let rearVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC2")

let rootVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController:rearVC ,frontViewController:frontVC)

self.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
```