# Time to set a property to pass it to another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have `tableViewController` class and want to pass a property to another view controller.

I declared my property,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selection;
```

In protocol `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I want to set my `selection` value into `indexPath` selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // change your selection property
    [self setSelection:indexPath];
}
```

I want to pass that `selection` into destination view controller by `prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"updateItem"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        UpdateViewController *viewController = (UpdateViewController *)[navController topViewController];

        [viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObject *record = [self.fetchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.selection];
        if (self.selection) {
            [viewController setRecord:record];
        }

        // reset selection
        [self setSelection:nil];
    }
```

My problem is, I NSlog-ing that property on destination view controller and for the first time it showed as null. Secondly, it showed as it set for the first, and so on and so on. It showed what I set before.

So did I miss the concept of setting a property before it goes into another view controller destination? Please let me know this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: where did you allocated 'selection'

Comment: I haven't allocate 'selection'. Just declare it as property in my private interface, and set it on my didSelectAtIndex protocol.

Comment: @RohitKP should i alloc init 'selection'?

Comment: Could you show logging code?

Comment: In viewDidLoad's destination controller > NSLog(@"Content: %@", [self.record valueForKey:@"name"]);  @MaximSysenko

Comment: At first, need to add additional NSLog before `if (self.selection) {`. By the way, why not to check for `recording` object in if statement?

Comment: NSLog before check 'self.selection' give me null for first try. I think my prepareForSegue runs before my didSelectRowAtIndexPath that set my 'selection'. @Maxim Sysenko

Comment: You also could check it by setting breakpoints in prepareForSegue and didSelect methods. How you trigger your segue? @SonicMaster

Comment: Ah, I checked it by using breakkpoint and my `prepareForSegue` run before my `didSelect`. I try to `performSegueWithIdentifier` on my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` too, but it still the same. My  `prepareForSegue` run before my `didSelect`, @MaximSysenko

Comment: Hi, @MaximSysenko! I think I messed up with segue, I should use either `performSegueWithIdentifier` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  I decide to use`performSegueWithIdentifier`, so I set `selection` there by `[[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow]`. Thank you so much, Maxim. Now it is solved.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, feel free to _answer_ your own question! That is perfectly legal on Stack Overflow. You can even accept your own answer in 2 days, to show everyone that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I messed up with how to trigger segue. `prepareForSegue` runs first before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18166148/2924335) we should use either of `prepareForSegue` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So I decide to set my `selection` in `prepareForSegue` by get its `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

```
[self setSelection:[[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow]
```