# Data sent on button press persists when different button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

**Issue**: I have a table view in complaintController which has "open" buttons in it. Whenever I press on the open button I segue to DetailComplaintViewController with the data of that row, but when I go back to ComplaintController and select a different button I am presented with the same data from previous selection.

**NOTE** - I have created a segue from button in cell of tableView.

This is the code I am using to segue from ComplaintController to DetailComplaintController.

```
var passRow = 0
        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

            let billCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "complaintCell") as! ComplaintTableViewCell
            billCell.openBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            billCell.openBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
            return billCell

    }

             func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
                    passRow = sender.tag
                    print("Position......\(sender.tag)")
                }

                override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                    let rVC = segue.destination as? DetailComplaintViewController
                    rVC?.issueType = self.complaintListArray[passRow].issueType
                    rVC?.issuedescription = self.complaintListArray[passRow].description
                    rVC?.issuedate = self.complaintListArray[passRow].issueDate
                }
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly exactly what you are facing?

Comment: The data from my previous selection is getting displayed even when I select a different button

Comment: Okay that mean you are getting wrong data even you select different open button in cell right?

Comment: Yaa I am getting wrong data

Comment: Then get the indexpath of that row and according to that row take the value from array and send it from Prepareforsegue method

Comment: I am doing that only , check my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152311/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-ojas-chimane).

Comment: How are you dismissing the detailComplainViewcontroller?? Can you please post the code of the detailComplaintViewController

Comment: I am not doing anything to dismiss detailComplainViewController

Comment: Then how can you go back to the complainViewController from the detail I think the issue is that the detailComplainViewctonroller is staying in the view hierarchy and is not being loaded again

Comment: Maybe,so what should I do to dismiss it

Comment: Can you send an image of your storyboard so I can understand the layout of your views so I can help you...it looks like your using a navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the prepare for segue will be called before your `btnClicked` function and thats why you are not getting the correct data.

A quick fix for your situation would be to get the button tag inside the prepare for segue method like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
        print("Segue was not called from button")
        return
    }
    let row = button.tag
    let rVC = segue.destination as? DetailComplaintViewController
    rVC?.issueType = self.complaintListArray[row].issueType
    rVC?.issuedescription = self.complaintListArray[row].description
    rVC?.issuedate = self.complaintListArray[row].issueDate
}
```

Other option is to remove the segue from the button and create it on the view controller and programatically perform that segue inside your `btnClicked` method which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18166148/6739471)