# iOS 8 : Disable UIBarButtonItem when shown inside a popover

Tags: ipad, swift, ios8, xcode6, uipopover

Now that XCode 6 and iOS 8 enable size classes, there is only one storyboard for all devices. Fine.
But in the same time, Apple recommends to avoid using bar button items to dismiss a popover.
Now, **how can I do to have a UIBarButtonItem when presenting on an iPhone, and not when presented inside a popover on an iPad** ?

Precision : I know how to disable a UIBarButtonItem based on the fact that the device is an iPad. I'm looking for a way to specifically detect that a popover is displayed.

EDIT: this code works, but I'd like something less device-dependent:

```
if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
```

EDIT: I created a small Github project to make my question clear :
[Github - Test Popover](https://github.com/FredddyF/Test-Popover)

Thanks!

Comment: check the the answers for the following question: [How can I find the UIPopoverController from the UIViewController being displayed in a popover?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177965/how-can-i-find-the-uipopovercontroller-from-the-uiviewcontroller-being-displayed

Comment: check the answers for the following question: [How can I find the UIPopoverController from the UIViewController being displayed in a popover?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177965/how-can-i-find-the-uipopovercontroller-from-the-uiviewcontroller-being-displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to solve that issue :

- In the storyboard, I removed the "close" bar button item in the navigation bar of the view controller I want to display as a popover on iPad and a modal VC on iPhone. So now this controller is embedded in a navigation controller, but without a "close" button.
  [image]
- In the **caller** view controller (the one which has a bar button item to call the popover), I added the following code in the prepareForSegue (my segue is a Popover segue by the way)

---

PrepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

// switch on the segue.identifier
// ....
       case .DisplayPreferences:
           print("Segue to Preferences")
           if let popoverPresentationController = segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController {
             popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
           }
// ....
}
```

---

- I added the following extension so that the caller view controler conforms to UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate protocol

---

UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate:

```
// MARK: - UIPopoverPresentationController Delegate methods
extension StockListTableViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .FullScreen
}


func presentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
    if let navigationVC = controller.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController,
        let preferencesVC = navigationVC.visibleViewController as? PreferencesTableViewController {
        // This Bool indicates whether the popover controller should display the bar button item or not
        preferencesVC.shouldShowCloseButton = true
    }
    return controller.presentedViewController
}
```

}

---

- Finally, in the **called** view controller (which is a popover on iPad but modal on iPhone), I added the following code:

---

property:

```
    var shouldShowCloseButton = false
```

---

viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Close button
    if shouldShowCloseButton {
        let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(PreferencesTableViewController.doneButtonTapped(_:)))
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(closeButton, animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

doneButtonTapped:

```
func doneButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

For me, this worked perfectly:

- on iPhone, I get a view controller presented modally, with a "close"
  button item in a navigation controller, which allows me to dismiss it
- on iPad, I get a popover without a "close" button because with a popover th expected behavior is to tap outside the  popover to
  dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably worked this out, now, but I find that this works:

```
if (self.popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) {
    // hide bar button item
} else {
    // show bar button item
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is dependent on the size class. I'd like a way to sepcifically check that the view controller is presented inside a popover.

Comment: Have you tried `if (self.presentationController.presentationStyle == UIModalPresentationPopover) { ... }`

Comment: You mean "== UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover" ? I just tried that, but it does not hide the button while inside a popover. I also tried "if self.navigationController.popoverPresentationController == nil", and "if self.popoverPresentationController == nil", without success.